# ./configure with a specified version of g++

Tags: gcc, version, autoconf, configure

How to tell to a 'configure' file to compile with a specified version of g++ ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In a bash shell you can do something like this:

```
./configure CC=gcc-2.95
```

There will be similar techniques for other shells but I couldn't help you with the specifics.  If your project is C++ the variable you need to define is `CXX`.

Comment: I don't even know how to call the wished version without configure...
I type only g++.

Comment: Actually, on my system, it was gcc-4.1 for gcc-4.1.2.

Thanks.

Comment: This works, but is discouraged.  The recommended way to specify CC is in an argument to configure, not in the environment.  In other words, you should do "./configure CC=/path/to/desired/compiler".

Comment: Actually, I needed `./configure CXX=g++-4.9`

Comment: is there a way to specify the compiler version even more, like: gcc-4.8.2?

Comment: This is such a perfect solution

Comment: @WilliamPursell I just find out if you build you own GCC compiler then only your case works. Thank you buddy!

Comment: Note that my comment from 2010 is no longer applicable, as the answer has been edited to include the recommended change.