# 'gem install ffi' picks the wrong compiler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xcode, gcc, rubygems

I'm trying to set up a RoR environment for my project on Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.5.
My preliminary setup include:

```
rvm
ruby-1.9.3-p194
gcc v.4.2
```

Then, I think everything was all set at that moment. Then I further moved on to the next step to install the gem I need for the project.
However, when I actually issued the command "gem install ffi -v '1.9.3'", I was getting 
an error as below

```
MacBook-Pro:demo-project apple$ sudo gem install ffi -v '1.9.3'
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ffi:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160429-33780-1iddmww.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
    --with-ffi_c-dir
    --without-ffi_c-dir
    --with-ffi_c-include
    --without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
    --with-ffi_c-lib
    --without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/lib
    --with-libffi-config
    --without-libffi-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
/Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in `try_cpp'
    from /Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:931:in `block in have_header'
    from /Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
    from /Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
    from /Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:930:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:16:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/1.9.1/ffi-1.9.3/gem_make.out
```

and as the error suggested, I then looked into the file mkmf.log in hope to get some useful information for possible corrective action.

```
cat /Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/1.9.1/ffi-1.9.3/mkmf.log
package configuration for libffi is not found
"gcc-4.9 -o conftest -I/Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin14.5.0 -I/Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE    -O3 -g  -O3 -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L. -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/lib     -lruby.1.9.1  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: int main() {return 0;}
/* end */
```

From there, I discovered the command basically try to link to the wrong compiler (gcc-4.9) - I had the version 4.9 installed before, but finally decided to remove it as understanding gcc-4.2 should work fine in my case.
Then the next idea that came to my mind was to get it to work by symbolic linking my installed gcc-4.2 (/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2) to /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9. and surprisingly, it seemed to work as shown below this time.

```
MacBook-Pro:demo-project apple$ sudo gem install ffi -v '1.9.3'
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed ffi-1.9.3
1 gem installed
```

However, the thing is I really don't want to do a little hack like that as considered that could bring me more problems sooner or later.
Anyone could tell me how I can get the "gem install ffi" command to link to the correct compiler in this case? I currently have got no idea where to look.
Thanks for your kind help, appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621019/configure-with-a-specified-version-of-g

Comment: There's a `You have to install development tools first.` message in the logs. Did you install them?

Comment: Also, 1.9.3 is not supported anymore. You might want to upgrade to 2.3.